swig unable to find 'vector'
I try to use a custom type of std::vector, but the standard library file cannot be found when generating the wrapper file.
My platform is windows 10 + swig 4.2.1
My file:
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(TrajPlanProj VERSION 0.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX "d")

##########################swig###############################
if ( MSVC )
  set(SWIG_DIR "C:\\Program Files\\swigwin-4.2.1\\Lib")
  set(SWIG_EXECUTABLE "C:\\Program Files\\swigwin-4.2.1\\swig.exe")  
endif (MSVC)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

# Set .Net project directory
# set(NET_PROJECT_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../CSharpSide")
set(NET_PROJECT_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

# Add swig flags here
set(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

set_property(SOURCE TrajPlan.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(TrajPlan.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")

swig_add_library(TrajPlan 
    TYPE SHARED
    LANGUAGE CSharp
    SOURCES TrajPlan.i TrajPlan.h
    OUTPUT_DIR ${NET_PROJECT_DIR}
    OUTFILE_DIR ${NET_PROJECT_DIR}
)

set_property(TARGET TrajPlan PROPERTY SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ON)


# for copying TrajPlan.dll to .Net project dir dir
set_target_properties( TrajPlan
    PROPERTIES

    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE ${NET_PROJECT_DIR}
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${NET_PROJECT_DIR}
    
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${NET_PROJECT_DIR}

    # Set address of C++ headers
    INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)

TrajPlan.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Point {
  float x;  
  float y;  
  float z;       
};


int addPoints(std::vector<Point> points){
  for(const auto& point : points){
    std::cout << "x: " << point.x << ", y: " << point.y << ", z: " << point.z << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

TrajPlan.i
%module TrajPlanModule

%{
#include "TrajPlan.h"
%}

%include <std_vector.i>

%template(PointVector)   std::vector<Point>;

%include "TrajPlan.h"

Report an error
[build] C:\program_on_git\SFR\trajplan\CppSide\TrajPlan.h(2): error : Unable to find 'iostream' [C:\program_on_git\SFR\trajplan\CppSide\out\build\vs+vcpkg\TrajPlan.vcxproj]
[build] C:\program_on_git\SFR\trajplan\CppSide\TrajPlan.h(3): error : Unable to find 'vector' [C:\program_on_git\SFR\trajplan\CppSide\out\build\vs+vcpkg\TrajPlan.vcxproj]

This seems to happen after using %include<std_vector.i>.I think I have already set the lib folder path of swig. Is there something wrong with this way of writing it?

It is just a file-not-found error.  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} seems very unlikely to be correct, be sure to specify your C++ compiler's include directory.

It looks like a compile error not finding the compiler's standard libraries.  As an aside, you normally do not want -includeall as a SWIG flag.  It will try to wrap all of iostream and vector.
